# Can I have some assistance with this integral calculation?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form

This integral has bothered me for the longest time: $$J=\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt[x]{2+\Gamma(x+1)}\space\text{dx}$$

This guy is extremely minuscule in relation to most other integrals but was amazingly difficult nonetheless. I ended up getting a reasonable solution, an ugly decimal form, which I checked with Wolfram Alpha to be true. That closed form is the following:

$$J=0.0496407...$$

But WA also has no closed form. As I am a student, I really don't have that much time to look at these things (I have been kind of teaching myself Calculus). I have made very many attempts, but the fact that I can't really break up that portion (because of the + sign), has thrown me for a loop. T I just really don't want to try too hard on this problem as I have homework and weight training later. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: How do you define $(-1/2)!$?

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to use $x!$ when you mean $\Gamma(x+1)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews didn't know that, will fix

Comment: Not every integral has a closed form. Is there a particular reason you think it should?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I feel like it does, but have no real constructive reason why/why not

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I though it was referring to Gamma function, but you know there is no reason to deduce it, in principle..

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are asking: are you asking about $$J=\int_{-1}^0 \Bigl(2+\Gamma(x+1)\Bigr)^{1/x}\,dx?$$

Comment: Neither $\int_{-1}^{0}\Gamma(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}\,dx=0.3079021\ldots$ has a nice closed form, so my feelings are the opposite of yours.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $\int_{-1}^0 (1+\Gamma(x+1))$ also has none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no closed form, because For all $k\in\Bbb{R}$

$$\int_{-1}^0 (k+(\Gamma(x+1)))^{1/x}dx$$
has no closed form.

Comment: The above statement has not been proven, but it is widely believed to be true.

Comment: The most logical answer I'm going to get.